# Angular 7 scroll event in component re rendering all components on scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scroll, angular7

I am using HostListener 'window:scroll' event in my component as shown in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-host-listener-scroll-y4xm1u?file=app/app.component.ts). While I scroll the components re render itself. In console I am printing sample text which is inside component that should run only one time.

Need help what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: thats how change detection works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering is triggered by the default change detection strategy.

Basically the `HeaderComponent` is triggered by `HostListener` to check the state of the component, which then propagates to the child components.

The `FirstComponent`'s change detector is by default `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`, because of which it re-checks the state each time change detection is triggered. The other option would be to set `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`.

This would make the component to check for changes only whenever the actual state is changed. For example when `Input()` or `Output()` is changed or when the template event is raised (`(click)="onClick()"` in HTML for example).

I would highly recommend to read more about the change detection mechanism in Angular in more details.

Here's the working solution:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  template: `{{abc()}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FirstComponent  {
  constructor() {}
  abc(){
    console.log('first component')
  }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Every day learning and never finish. Thanks!